# Unity2D/C#: How do I make a raycast ignore its first collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

One of the features of the raycast controller for my platformer game is that the player can jump down through 1-way platforms. This works nicely, but I wanted to add additional functionality where the player will only be able to jump down if the platform to which he or she will jump is within a certain distance.

My platform controller's functionality for jumping down works like this:

1. My character shoots a ray from below its box collider, and detects if it's on ground or not.
2. If it is, and if the ground is tagged as a 1-way platform, and the player presses the jump down button, it will jump down to the next platform, regardless of distance.

I have tried making a jump down method that creates a new raycast from the center of the character's box collider (which is not shown in the code below, as I have been entirely unsuccessful so far), and checks for a collision at a certain distance. My problem is that it always detects the collider of the platform from which it is about to jump down, and never gets a chance to detect anything else.

How do I get this new raycast to ignore the first collision, potentially detect a collision within the ray’s distance, and if it hits something allow my character to jump down? Also, do I even need to do a new raycast, or can I just use the current raycasts on my controller?

Here's a bit of my raycast controller script that hopefully explains some of the functionality:

```
private void MoveVertically(ref Vector3 deltaMovement)
{
    float directionY = Mathf.Sign(deltaMovement.y);
    float rayLength = Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.y) + skinWidth;

    for (int i = 0; i < verticalRayCount; i++)
    {
        Vector2 rayOrigin = (directionY == -1) ? raycastOrigins.bottomLeft : raycastOrigins.topLeft;
        rayOrigin += Vector2.right * (verticalRaySpacing * i + deltaMovement.x);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, Vector2.up * directionY, rayLength, collisionMask);

        Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, Vector2.up * directionY * rayLength, Color.red);

        if (hit)
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "platformOneWay")
            {
                if (directionY == 1)
                {
                    State.IsCollidingWithOneWay = true;
                    State.IsCollidingAbove = false;
                    continue;
                }

                if (CanJumpDown)
                {
                    State.IsCollidingBelow = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            deltaMovement.y = (hit.distance - skinWidth) * directionY;
            rayLength = hit.distance;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, Unity3D provides an API called `Physics2D.RaycastAll` that returns not only the first raycast hit but all raycast hits within the maximum distance as an array.
`Physics2D.RaycastAll` takes two `Vector2` as parameters (the raycast origin and direction) and returns an array of `RaycastHit2D`, which is ordered by the distance from the origin to the hit point.
Here is a bit of code that shows you what this function does:

```
public class Raycaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, Vector2.down);
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; ++i)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("The name of collider {0} is \"{1}\".", 
                i, hits[i].collider.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just implemented this, and it worked perfectly. Thanks for letting me know about this API.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create LayerMasks. Create a new layer in the Unity editor and assign the layer to the Game Object where your collider is attached it.

Get the layer mask ID in your code using `LayerMask.GetMask` and add it as an parameter. Now your Raycast will only cast colliders assigned to the layer.

```
var layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("myLayerName");
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100.0f, layerMask)) {
    Debug.Log ("Got ya!");
}
```

Comment: While this *might* work, what if we wanted the *second* object of `Layer_3`? That is, both results (the first thing hit and the thing we want) are on the same physics layer.